# PowerShell ps1 scripts open in Notepad by default, not in PowerShell ISE. Why's that?

Tags: powershell

I regularly have to spin up VMs, and then I have to switch the .ps1 and .psm1 file association from Notepad to the PowerShell ISE.

Does anyone know why it's not the default editor to begin with?
It doesn't auto-run the script, so I wouldn't consider it a security flaw.

Comment: You have failed to mention the operating system.

Comment: I wasn't aware PowerShell existed on anything but Windows.

Comment: Oh, perhaps you meant what version of Windows. All of them that PowerShell ships with: 7, 8, 8.1, and probably Vista and Server versions, too. The default file association is always Notepad.

Comment: Only Microsoft could answer this question.

Comment: Lucky for me, some of them are on StackExchange, as are business partners and power users who have direct contact with folks at Microsoft. Either way, let's hope someone has insight.

Answer (score 3):

You almost answered your own question : This is a security measure.

The Windows PowerShell Blog article [Windows PowerShell and the "PowerShell Worm"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/08/03/687838.aspx)
details the security features of PowerShell, which are also summed up in the article
[PowerShell Security](https://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2007/07/27/powershell-security/) :

> PowerShell has been obviously designed with much more security in mind
> than VBScript or cmd.exe:
>
> 1. By default .ps1 script files are associated with Notepad. Double-clicking a script does not start it.
> 2. To reference a script in PowerShell you have to specify file path, so even if a script is called dir.ps1 typing in dir will not start it.
>    The shortest way to reference it is .\dir.ps1.
> 3. And finally [execution policies](https://web.archive.org/web/20091025151241/http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/topics/msh/cmdlets/set-executionpolicy.mspx) by default won’t allow you to run any scripts at all. You can lift the limitation up a bit by
>    allowing to run scripts signed by trusted authorities.

Comment: Oh, but this isn't a question about running the script. Just editing it in the editor that ships with Windows but isn't associated with the file type.

Comment: PowerShell ISE was introduced in PowerShell V2 and was an optional component not installed by default. So notepad was since always the script editor. Second, it's an IDE rather than an editor and is not as simple to use, while everybody knows notepad. Third, it's slow to launch while notepad is immediate. Fourth, only in PowerShell V3 did ISE become much more useful than notepad.

Comment: Although v2 had a debugger, so it was more useful than notepad. And installing the optional Windows component could have installed the file association.

Comment: In that case the double-click would behave differently on computers where ISE was installed or not. For administrators of multiple computers this would be insupportable, so Microsoft (as always) took the path of the least common denominator.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of opening in a text editor is by design.  The reasons why are a bit nuanced and those of us that were around when Microsoft first started with Powershell remember it.  You're not likely to find it written down somewhere, but Ed Wilson may have touched on it in his first Powershell book or on his blog.

Powershell was developed for a specific audience, the Systems Administrator, not the general public or technician.  It's open for all to use, but it was *designed* for a specific group.  While the ISE is nice, it's resource intensive and not the go to resource for sysadmins.  If we're scripting from scratch or doing a major overhaul of a script, sure we'll use the ISE.  But most times when we have to touch a script it's to make a specific and quick change, or confirm a detail.

Sysadmins typically prefer whatever is faster or the right tool for the job.  In this case, that's reviewing a script in a plain old text editor.  There's also the old adage that people don't like change and that can apply her as well.  Prior to Powershell we sysadmins scripted in batch, vbs, python, etc which are all text editor based.  Microsoft likely considered that too much change at once would detract from folx adopting their new shell platform.  [This link might give you some insight](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177003.aspx)